# ROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RuntimeError: Aborted(native code called abort()) RuntimeError: Aborted(native code called abort()) mediapipe angula

Tags: angular

Hola buen dia me da error el siguiente error al usar media pipe en angular, estoy utilizando la libreria npm de hands de mediapipe, la version de angular es la 16 y la version de mediapipe es la 0.4.1675469240

```
ROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RuntimeError: Aborted(native code called abort())
RuntimeError: Aborted(native code called abort())
   at abort (hands_solution_simd_wasm_bin.js:9:25546)
   at _abort (hands_solution_simd_wasm_bin.js:9:163781)
   at hands_solution_simd_wasm_bin.wasm:0x51ad24
   at hands_solution_simd_wasm_bin.wasm:0x51abc9
   at hands_solution_simd_wasm_bin.wasm:0x51ad99
   at hands_solution_simd_wasm_bin.wasm:0x1f191
   at hands_solution_simd_wasm_bin.wasm:0x198f7
   at SolutionWasm.SolutionWasm$send [as send] (eval at new_ 
(hands_solution_simd_wasm_bin.js:9:140730), <anonymous>:9:1)
   at ra.i (hands.js:82:499)
   at ua (hands.js:14:299)
   at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
   at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:17)
   at zone.js:1278:17
   at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
   at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26261:33)
   at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
   at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
   at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:35)
handleError @ core.mjs:9171
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.